# What’s the difference between form:form and sf:form in spring?

Tags: java, spring

What’s the difference between form:form and sf:form in spring ,
I don't understand the difference bewteen
`<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` and 
`<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`,is the difference just prefix or something else?

for example

```
<sf:form method="post" action="form/submit" commandName="user">
    <sf:input path="ID"></sf:input>
    <sf:input path="name"></sf:input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</sf:form>

<form:form method="post" action="form/submit" modelAttribute="user">
    <form:input path="ID"></form:input>
    <form:input path="name"></form:input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>
```

Comment: The is no difference between these two prefixes.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing. It's just the prefix that you give to the uri:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

You can write anything in the prefix and use it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="foo" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<foo:form method="post" action="form/submit" commandName="user">
    <foo:input path="ID"></foo:input>
    <foo:input path="name"></foo:input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</foo:form>
```